# ANTD Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event

Tags: reactjs, antd

i'm used Antd components.After click on component example checkbox or select a warning appears.
How fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV25l.png)

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: https://github.com/Zandess/Internet-shop/blob/main/src/components/CatalogInner/CatalogInner.jsx code this component where does this warning happen